# encrypt a password using pbkdf2-sha256 in ionic2

Tags: ionic2, sha256, pbkdf2

> how to encrpt password in ionic2 typescript file.I refered the below link and imported pbkdf2 module  in to  ionic2 app.
>   [enter link description here](http://cryptocoinjs.com/modules/crypto/pbkdf2-sha256/)
>
> but i got error like  **webpack_require**.i(...) is not a function.can anyone help me solving out this...

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { pbkdf2 } from '../../../node_modules/pbkdf2-sha256/lib/pbkdf2.js';
/*
  Generated class for the Firstpage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-firstpage',
  templateUrl: 'firstpage.html'
})
export class FirstpagePage {
  key : any = "passwd";
  salt :any ="salt";
  res :any ; 
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad FirstpagePage');
  }
  encrypt(){
  console.log("-----");
  
 this.res = pbkdf2(this.key, this.salt, 1, 64);
 console.log(this.res.toString('hex')) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to define `pbkdf2` in the constructor.

```js
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
 public crypt:pbkdf2) {}
```